# How can I do the Levene's test using lapply function

Tags: r, linear-regression, lapply, anova

How can I do the Levene's test (car package) of my regressions? For my regressions I used the lapply function.

Here is my code

```
library(data.table)

Regressions<- 
data.table(February)[, 
                  .(Lm = lapply(.SD, function(x) summary(lm(February$PPNA ~ February$Acum1 + x)))),
                  .SDcols = 80:157]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a grouping column ('group'), then we loop over the columns of interest from `.SDcols`, apply the `levene.test` with that column value and the group

```
library(data.table)
library(car)
as.data.table(February)[, 
              .(Lm = lapply(.SD, function(x) list(levene.test(x, group)))),
              .SDcols = 80:157]
```

Comment: I have not a grouping column ('group')

Comment: @Pablo do you have a column 'PPNA`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I did not know that the levene test is not appropriate with quantitative explanatory variables, so I used bptest from the lmtest package

Comment: Hi akrun, I asked another question on stackoverflow. Can you help me? [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254073/how-can-i-get-the-shapiro-wilk-test)

Comment: @Pablo sure, will check it out