# How can i get the shapiro-wilk test

Tags: r, linear-regression, lapply, anova

I want to do the shapiro-wilk test for my regressions. Here is my code

```
library(data.table)

Regresiones_shapirotest_1<- 
data.table(tabla.Enero)[, 
                      .(Lm = lapply(.SD, function(x) resid(lm(tabla.Enero$PPNA ~  x)))),
                      .SDcols = 15:93]
```

I can get the test values only in the console

```
 Regresiones_shapirotest_1 [, lapply(Lm, shapiro.test)]   [2]


 write.xlsx (Regresiones_shapirotest_1 , file = "shapirotest.xlsx", sheetName = "Hoja1",
        Col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE, append = FALSE)
```

But when I try to export them in an .xlsx file, it exports a lot of values that have nothing to do with console values. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey what is the output of class( Regresiones_shapirotest_1) ?

Comment: `str(Regresiones_shapirotest_1)` Returns this: `Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 79 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Lm:List of 79
  ..$ : Named num  64.6 -77.3 46.2 102.1 -45.5 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...`

Comment: looks like you have a list inside of a dataframe giving you troubles